# Azure devops deploy iOS app to firebase app distribution

Tags: firebase, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline that builds iOS application. I am looking for a way to deploy the .ipa file to Firebase App distribution. I couldn't find any document or reference that provides the steps to do that. I saw few articles that explains we could publish to Firebase app distribution using PowerShell. Is there a reference azure pipeline yaml that I could refer? I am pretty new to Azure DevOps pipeline and can't get past this step.

Comment: You can refer to [How to build and sign your iOS application using Azure DevOps](https://damienaicheh.github.io/ios/azure/devops/2019/12/05/build-sign-your-ios-application-using-azure-devops-en.html)
and 
[azure-devops-yaml-generator](https://github.com/damienaicheh/azure-devops-yaml-generator/blob/master/templates/ios.stages.yml.tmpl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to install Firebase and distribute the app IPA to Firebase app distribution. In case, if anyone is looking for an answer:

```
# Install Firebase tools
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Firebase Tools'
  inputs:
    script: 'curl -sL firebase.tools | bash'
    workingDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Deploy IPA to Firebase'
  inputs:
    script: |
      firebase appdistribution:distribute *.ipa \
      --app "$(appId)" \
      --token "$(FIREBASE_TOKEN)" \
      --release-notes "$BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE"
    workingDirectory: '$(agent.buildDirectory)/output/$(sdk)/${{ parameters.configuration }}'
```

Comment: Hey @alexander still I’m getting errror /Users/runner/work/_temp/8fd067be-b678-455c-b30b-e1f33632cc0e.sh: line 1: FIREBASE_TOKEN: command not found

Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?